# How can i make wrap_content work when i have a 2 lines tint string

Tags: android, android-edittext

android EditText's height is wrap_content in xml and tint string is more than 2 lines. When i call setText with only a few words, the EditText's line count seems to be 2 lines but not 1 line. How can i make wrap_content work when i have a 2 lines tint string.

**picture with tint being show**

[image]

**picture after setting text**

[image]

**my xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lemon.edittexttintdemo.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="this is a very long tint string which is more than one line"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one line text example"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText.setText("In fact there is only one line");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Put Line above the editText.setText("line");

editText.setHint("");

Comment: this will remove hint. if user edits and make edittext empty. it won't show hint again.

Comment: so you must set a TextWatcher to reset hint when user make edittext empty@vrundpurohit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final EditText t = findViewById(someName);
    t.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            t.setSingleLine(t.getText().toString().length() > 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can use `onTextChanged` rather than using `afterTextChanged`.

Comment: i hope wrap_content work means that user can enter words without limitation, so the line count may be 3,4 or 1. But your solution limits line count to 1.
Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0):

Hey try out this solution.

```
final EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
t.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if (t.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            t.setHint("");
        } else {
            t.setHint("this is a very long tint string which is more than one line");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Happy coding.

Comment: yes, i have solved my problem like what you said. @vrundpurohit